# Limiting number of calls to an WCF Web Service

Tags: wcf, web-services

We are planning to develop a web service using WCF. Is there a good way to limit the number of calls to the service in a period of time for a single IP? We don't want to put a hard limit (X number of times an hour), but we want to be able to prevent a spike from a single user.

Rather than trying to come up with our own custom solution and reinventing the wheel, is there an existing implementation or strategy that can be used?  Will the different hosting environments in WCF make any difference?

Note:  This question is related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588778/limiting-number-of-calls-to-an-asmx-web-service).  Comments were made about better extensibility in WCF, so I'm keeping these two questions separate.

Comment: How is this not just a duplicate of your first question?

Comment: I assume this is self hosted wcf and no IIS involved.

Comment: John, you edited the title of the previous question to be ASMX specific and you mentioned in your answer that WCF had better extensibility.

Comment: Did you find a solution?  I am faced with the same issue with a WCF web service.